# Wrong number of posts being displayed on my blogger blog's homepage, need solution

Tags: redirect, settings, blogs, blogger, blogspot

I have already changed this the normal way from both the settings and from the layout section and want to show 7 posts on my blog's homepage but it only shows 3 posts and when I go to the 2nd page of posts it shows 6-7 posts. I don't know how to fix this. My blog's link is [http://bloggersliveonline.blogspot.in/](http://bloggersliveonline.blogspot.com) and as you can see for yourself, there are only 3 posts on the first page. I have been trying to fix this for a long time but nothing seems to work and even when I write new posts, it doesn't seem to change. I actually don't remember where I got this template from and have worked too hard on it to change it now. Is there any code I can change or a way to redirect people to a home page with a slightly altered URL showing 7 posts correctly?

Comment: Can You Please Upload The ScreenShot of `Configure dialog box for your blog`

Comment: Checked This:  http://blogtimenow.com/blogging/limit-change-number-posts-displayed-blogger-homepage/

Comment: I don't know what that is and where to find it. And I have already changed the basic settings from blogger, it didn't work, what I need is a code or something to show 7 posts on the homepage.

Comment: Are You Notice That `Blogger Page Size is Restricted up to 1mb So suggest you to lower the number of posts in homepage`.